# Table view cell get initial value after scrolling

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have a table view and 10 different prototype cell. I used storyboard and created custom UITableCell class for each cell.
There is a checkbox in CheckBoxCell. I created these checkboxes in loop according to options count.

Problem is that after I checked a checkbox, checkbox value changes but when I scroll up or down the table view, checkbox value changes with inital value.

I investigated some questions in stackoverflow. I live this problem, because of after every scroll dequeReusebleCell works and re-create the cell in the queue. I tried to use these solutions, but I cannot succeeded.

I am new for Swift and I don't know how can I solve this problem. 
May someone tell me how can I solve this problem and what is the correct approach?

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

let object = surveyDetailArray.first!.elements[indexPath.row]
switch object.type {

    case CellConfig.checkbox.rawValue:

     let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CheckboxCell", for: indexPath) as! CheckboxCell

     let object = surveyDetailArray.first!.elements[indexPath.row]

     for label in object.options {

            cell.checkbox = BEMCheckBox()
            cell.checkbox.onAnimationType = .bounce
            cell.checkbox.offAnimationType = .bounce
            cell.checkbox.boxType = .square
            cell.checkbox.onFillColor = .red
            cell.checkbox.offFillColor = .white
            cell.checkbox.onCheckColor = .white
            cell.checkbox.delegate = self
            cell.checkbox.tag = label.id

            cell.contentView.addSubview(cell.checkbox)
      }

  return cell
  }
```

Comment: This code doesn't compile and makes no sense. On **each** call of `cellForRowAt` – and this method is called pretty frequently – one or multiple new checkboxes are added to the cell. I recommend to design the cells in Interface Builder. To preserve the state of the checkbox(es) you have to save it in the data model.

Comment: The `dequeue` method will reuse a cell if one is available but it doesn't clear out what was in it the first time it was created and used. So you need to make sure you only create and add a new checkbox if the cell hasn't been used previously and make sure to correctly set the value each time. Don't rely on any default (non-state) value.

Answer (score 0):

In your problem the cell is dequeuing and is getting back to the old state, that's will obviously happen because of dequeReusableCell,
now for the solution, you should use a model to store the states of different checkboxes and on cellforRowAt 
add the code for checkbox persistance according to the model, when you enable a checkbox, 
change the value of the variable in the model also and leave rest it on your cellForRowAt code. I'm adding a small example for your understanding, hope it helps.

**CODE**

```
Struct ButtonsStates {
   var isButtonEnabled : Bool = false 
}

// In your ViewController use the above model for saving buttonValues
   var buttonStates : [ButtonStates]? // initialize as many as the rows

// in cellForRowAt 
   guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ExampleCell", for: indexPath) as? ExampleCell else { return fatalError("") }

 // here if the cell is dequeued still when cell will again be visible then this condition will be checked 
  cell.customButton.isSelected = buttonStates[indexPath.row].isButtonEnabled
   return cell
```